# "gcloud auth activate-service-account" and "gcloud source repos clone" error

Tags: git, docker, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-sdk

I would like to use the following tools together:

- [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)
- [gcloud SDK](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/)
- gcloud Service Account
- gcloud Source Repo (as part of project dependencies)

The steps i'm taking:

1) Log into the Google Cloud Console at:
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=project-name

2) Create a service account, for now give 'Owner' permissions, and download the json key as account-name.json

[image]

3) Add a Dockerfile:

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk
COPY account-name.json /tmp/account-name.json
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/account-name.json
RUN rm /tmp/account-name.json
RUN gcloud config set project project-name
RUN gcloud config set account account-name@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com
RUN gcloud source repos clone default --project=project-name
```

4) Build and run docker:

```
docker build  -t service-account-repo .
docker run -ti service-account-repo
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) You do not currently have an active
>   account selected. Please run:
>
> $ gcloud auth login
>
> to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
>   different account:
>
> $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
>
> to select an already authenticated account to use.

And no matter which commands I try, including setting the account and auth login, via docker exec it doesn't work.

If I run the same commands locally it works, because I am already logged in with my main gcloud account.

Do gcloud Service Accounts work with gcloud Source Repos? does anyone have a working example without their normal accounts logged in? Do I need to enable other cloud APIs to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

The only `gcloud` command you need to run is

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/account-name.json
```

It sets `core/account` property. After that

```
gcloud source repos clone default --project=project-name
```

should work (no need to set project since you specifying part of the command).

Make sure to have `git` installed and it must be on the path.

One thing to note that `gcloud` stores activated credentials in `~/.config/gcloud` directory. This might not be what you want. You can change it by setting `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` environment variable to point to another location, preferably not part of the docker image itself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have followed those steps, and it doesn't allow access to the project. Did you try my example? does it work for you?

Comment: Can you specify which dockerfile you're using, or you used your custom dockerfile?